# How can I localize an asp-action using Localizer

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am building a webstie in multiple languages and would like the `asp-action` to be customised depending on the language. The idea is that the URL in the English version is something like `/en/feedback` whilst in German it should be `/de/gaestestimmen`.

I have tried the following:

```
<a asp-controller="Home" 
   asp-action="@Localizer["navKontakt"]" 
   asp-route-lang="@CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName">
     @Localizer["navFeedback"]
</a>
```

The Localizer returns the correct text in the second instance, but not for the `asp-action` - there it returns:

"`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization.LocalizedHtmlString`" instead of the expected string.

If I just enter `asp-action="Feedback"`it works fine.

Anyone any idea how I can make this work?

Answer (score 5):

Found the answer. As the localizer retuns a LocalizedHtmlString which is an object but not a string, I have to add the .Value to get value as a string.

```
asp-action="@Localizer["navKontakt"].Value"
```

Comment: This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39792066/net-core-localization-view-iviewlocalizer-inside-linq-expression). I find this syntax inconsistent and I doubt if it was by design.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a quotes issue. Try switching out the double quotes for the attribute value with single quotes:

```
<a asp-controller="Home"
    asp-action='@Localizer["navKontakt"]'
    asp-route-lang="@CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName">
    @Localizer["navFeedback"]
</a>
```