# .Net Core Localization View: IViewLocalizer inside Linq expression

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, linq-expressions, asp.net-core-localization

i'm writing mvc app in .net core, i have problem with localization, i don't know how to add  IViewLocalizer to  my grid view. Here is my code:

```
@using NonFactors.Mvc.Grid;
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer
@model IEnumerable<WeegreeEmployeeFormsCore.Models.Employee>

@(Html
    .Grid(Model)
    .Build(columns =>
    {
        columns.Add(model => model.Name).Titled(Localizer["Name"]).Sortable(true).Filterable(true);
        columns.Add(model => model.Surname).Titled(Localizer["Surname"]).Sortable(true).Filterable(true);
        columns.Add(model => model.EmploymentDate).Titled(Localizer["Hired"]).Sortable(true).Filterable(true);
        columns.Add(model => model.Country).Titled(Localizer["Country"]).Filterable(true).Sortable(true).Filterable(true);
        columns.Add(model => model.EmploymentForm).Titled(Localizer["EmploymentForm"]).Filterable(true);
        columns.Add(model => $"<a href=\"{Url.Action("Edit", "Form")}/{model.EmployeeId}\">{Localizer["Edit"]}</a>").Encoded(false);
        columns.Add(model => $"<a href=\"{Url.Action("Details", "Form")}/{model.EmployeeId}\">Details</a>").Encoded(false);


    })
    .Pageable(pager =>
    {
        pager.PagesToDisplay = 10;
        pager.CurrentPage = 1;
        pager.RowsPerPage = 10;
    })
    .Sortable()
    .Empty("No data found")

)
```

when i use `{}` to insert inside expression `model.EmployeeId` it works - link is working, but when i want to use Localizer to get inscription `Edit/Edytuj/змінити etc`. instead of i got this in my view :
    `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization.LocalizedHtmlString`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because  `IViewLocalizer["Foo"]` returns a [`LocalizedHtmlString`](https://docs.asp.net/projects/api/en/latest/autoapi/Microsoft/AspNetCore/Mvc/Localization/LocalizedHtmlString/index.html#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization.LocalizedHtmlString) instead of a string. So when you include that in a string interpolation expression, it is calling its ToString method. As ToString has not been redefined in that class, the default `Object.ToString()` implementation returns the type name:

```
var foo = Localizer["Foo"].ToString();
//foo gets assigned "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization.LocalizedHtmlString"
```

Razor knows how to handle LocalizedHtmlString instances when rendering a page, so this renders as expected:

```
<p>Hello @Localizer["World"]</p>
//renders <p>Hello World</p>
```

If you want to manually concatenate the localized string, then you need to make sure you get the [`LocalizedHtmlString.Value`](https://docs.asp.net/projects/api/en/latest/autoapi/Microsoft/AspNetCore/Mvc/Localization/LocalizedHtmlString/index.html#prop-Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization.LocalizedHtmlString.Value) property:

```
@{
    var text = $"Hello {Localizer["World"].Value}";
}
<p>@text</p>
//renders <p>Hello World</p>
```

Compare that with your approach without calling `.Value`:

```
@{
    var text = $"Hello {Localizer["World"]}";
}
<p>@text</p>
//renders <p>Hello Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization.LocalizedHtmlString</p>
```

Comment: In my opinion this is not by design, in fact if feels like a mistake by Microsoft. It is not explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization)

Comment: Be careful using `.Value` as [the documentation says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.localization.localizedhtmlstring.value?view=aspnetcore-5.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Localization_LocalizedHtmlString_Value) it's the - "The original resource string, prior to formatting with any constructor arguments.". So using `Localizer["some key {0} and {1}", some, arguments]` will not work and will return `some key {0} and {1}` instead of the formatted string.

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar problem when trying to pass Localization with multiple values into a partial view.  I was able to solve it by using the [WriteTo()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.localization.localizedhtmlstring?view=aspnetcore-2.2) method.

```
@{
    var writer = new StringWriter();
    Localizer["heading", Model.UserName].WriteTo(writer, HtmlEncoder.Default);
    var heading = writer.ToString();
}

@await Html.PartialAsync("_ModalHeader", new ModalHeaderModel { Heading = heading })
```

Answer (score 1):

As the accepted answer can be a bit misleading in regards to interpolation queries.

Internally the `Localizer` finds the text and runs it through `string.Format`. This enables us to feed it with strings like `pseudoText > This text will be {0} by the {1}`.

To modify what's in the braces

```
@Localizer["pseudoText", "transformed", "lozalizer"].
```

This will output `This text will be transformed by the lozalizer`